# SQL File won't restore

Tags: mysql, centos, centos6

What I have done:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost gx < gxe.sql
```

Result:

```
[root@jony html]# mysql -u root -p -h localhost gx < gxe.sql
Enter password:
[root@jony html]#
```

It actually doesn't do anything.. I tried refreshing my SQL client (Heidi SQL), and still nothing?.
What have I done wrong? Thanks!

OS: CentOS 6 - Linux

Comment: It's difficult or impossible to say without knowing what `gxe.sql` contains. For all we know, it's empty, and that's exactly what should happen.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` and `mysqldump` have slightly different syntax

`mysql` needs `-D` parameter to set the database.

So try

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -D gx < gxe.sql
```